# MCU interface to detect a wide input voltage

Tags: gpio

I am designing a new circuit, where I need to detect presence of voltage on an external network. Note that I am using the same network (Using LDO) to power up my circuit, so the ground is common. I want to keep it cheap, so cannot afford opto-coupler. The range of voltage to detect is somewhere from 5V to 40V. How can I achieve this using a BJT or MOSFET? Transistor is the only part, that always confuses me :( Can I do something simple like driving the base of the BJT with the external voltage and then sense the collector for low signal? We'll pull up the collector with a resistance. I need some suggestions on this please.

I need to detect LOGIC HI-LOW and not measure the external voltage (using ADC).  I need couple of such inputs.. So need to use GPIO :( My ADC is doing something else and there I am using voltage divider.

Note: My MCU operates at 4V and manual says the GPIO works with 3V

[image]

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF9gNO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will something like this work and safe to use?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info): Why do you think you need a BJT or MOSFET? You need a boring voltage divider, and use the ADC that your MCU contains. By the way, 4V is a pretty uncommon operating voltage for MCUs, but might be in the operating range of many MCUs, but I have my doubts about your 3V GPIO. Please tell us the exact type, or even better, link to the MCU datasheet in your question.

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller, I have added 2 pictures from my MCU datasheet. It's Quectel MC60. its a combined GNSS/GSM Module along with user program space. I cannot use voltage divider as the external voltage can vary from 5V-40V. Its not definite. :( BTW, I need to detect HI-LOW and not measure it (ADC) :)

Comment: the whole point of the voltage divider is to ... divide your voltage range into a range that your MCU can measure, so **yes**, you need a voltage divider of sorts, I'm pretty confident.

Comment: What is the maximum voltage that must be detected as off?

Comment: The range is huge here 5-40, anything below 5 needs to be treated as OFF. So when it is in the range of 5-40 V, we should detect it as ON. If I do a voltage divider, then when the voltage will come to a low level (like 6-7 volt), the divider will produce too low volt that MCU may not detect as a LOGIC 1. So trying to avoid divider.

Comment: why do you try to do this with a GPIO pin? is your ADC pin already occupied otherwise?

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller, I need couple of such inputs.. So need to use GPIO :( and particularly I need Logical HIGH/LOW, no need of the exact voltage. My ADC is doing something else and there I am using voltage divider as suggested by you..

Comment: Add that info to the question instead of adding more comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Constant-current sources make universal inputs easy

A wide-range input like this sounds hard, until you realize that:

1. LEDs (including those in optocouplers) are *constant current* devices
2. Small current sources are not nearly as unobtanium as your Circuits 1 professor might have told you

Thus, we present the circuit, in all its stark simplicity.  The LM334 + resistor current source is probably easier to obtain than a constant-current diode or suitable JFET, so it's preferred despite its slightly higher parts count.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMRHEX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The advantage of this over the comparator solution is that it's *isolated* which can save your microcontroller from frying, and that it's fewer parts.  You can add series diodes or a series Zener to roughly adjust the threshold if needed, by the way -- it starts off around ~2.8-3V as the combination of the minimum compliance voltage of I1 and the Vf of the optocoupler LED.  Of course, this isn't nearly as precise/accurate as a comparator and reference, but who cares?

Comment: Hi @ThreePhaseEeel, as I said, I need to keep this damn cheap. After searching a lot, I have found these two (CCR and Opto). Could you please let me know if I can go with these 2? mouser.com/ds/2/239/S_110_6N138-L,%206N139-L-337278.pdf and mouser.com/ds/2/115/BCR402UW6Q-1115172.pdf

Comment: @RakeshMehta The BCR402 is designed to drive LEDs at modest power, not at the low currents discussed here -- if nothing else, you may be able to use a JFET+resistor solution if you can find the right JFET

Answer (score 1):

If you need a threshold, simply implement a threshold!

Comparators are made for that. So:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxtUIm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thresholding is what analog comparators do. I used the R5->D1 combination to give you a stable reference voltage that the variable R6 can divide down to give you the 0.318 V threshold you need to detect 5V on the input.

You can replace R5->D1 with a voltage source that your module probable brings (3.3V or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

PIN 6 of the MC60 module is an ADC with an input range of 0 to 2.6 V.

So you need to divide your 5 to 40 V down to that; \$\frac{40}{2.6}\approx 16\$, so you need a 1:16 voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIY19g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That's really easy!

Realistically, you want to use "preferred series" resistor values, so R1=10kΩ, R2=680Ω is pretty close :)

Comment: Its not ADC (Sorry I mentioned that in the comment only). Its to detect LOGIC HIGH / LOW. Too low volt on divider may not be detected as LOGIC HIGH by the MCU. In that case I need to give it a try and see if MCU can detect it..

Comment: OK, edit your question and include **all** the info you gave us in comments in the question. It's kind of frustrating to answer a question and then be greeted with a "sorry, I forgot to mention". Writing a complete problem description is what *you* **must** do *before* asking.

Comment: Sorry, edited the question...  I hope things are clear now.. I mean the question can express what I need.

Comment: No. You didn't add **all** info. Where's the type of the MCU in your question?